# induction inequality

Tags: induction

I'm trying to solve the induction:

$ 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + ...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > 2\sqrt{n+1} -2 $

My thought for solving this was:

$f(k) = 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + ...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$

$f(k) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} > 2\sqrt{k+2} -2$ - Need to proof

and I know that :

$f(k) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} > 2\sqrt{k+1} -2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} $

So if I will try to show that :

$2\sqrt{k+1} -2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} > 2\sqrt{k+2} -2$

I manged to show that if I do square power to both sides of the equation (which keeps the inequality )the left side is bigger.
I wanted to know if this way of thinking is good and valid, and if there are other ways to solve it, because I'm new to this concept.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basis for induction: $n=1$ gives LHS = $1$ and RHS = $0.828...$ so true

Get rid of the $2$ in your last inequality so LHS becomes $\frac{2k+3}{\sqrt{k+1}}$. This gives the inequality $$2k+3>2\sqrt{k^2+3k+2} \Leftarrow 4k^2 + 12k + 9 > 4k^2 +12k + 8$$ which is clearly true so the inequality $$1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} + ...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > 2\sqrt{n+1} -2$$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.